# CK Editor data not save properly in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I am using CK editor library with codeigniter. I have post data with ck editor textarea. Data is post in format like :-

```
  'active' => string '1' (length=1)
  'restaurant_id' => string '60' (length=2)
  'title' => string 'Test' (length=22)
  'details' => string '<p><strong><span style="font-size:48px">This is test.</span></strong></p>' (length=75)
```

Here the data is posted correctly. but when i passed into insert method for inserting into it table then the format is destroy which i post:-

This is show like

```
array (size=8)
  'active' => string '1' (length=1)
  'restaurant_id' => string '60' (length=2)
  'title' => string 'Test' (length=22)
  'details' => string '<p><strong><span  is test.</span></strong></p>' (length=46)
```

How can i properly insert data into database.

Comment: that `span` tag is redundant. I suggest apply the formatting on the `strong` tag.

Comment: span tag is automatically generated by ckeditor. @Ormoz

Comment: If the markup is correct in the `$_POST` variable (you can find out by using `print_r($_POST)` , then there is no problem with `ckeditor`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all it would be useful to see your save-to-db code
but i assume you are using double quotes in your sql statement? replacing those with single should do the trick.
if the problem occurs on POST than you should show both the initial form and the receiving php script.